# Pandas create series based on 100

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create and index based on the starting value of 100.

I can do a loop and this does work, but I know there is a better way to do this in a single line of code.

So I have a series with the percentage changes like:

```
df['pct_chg'] = [0, 1.5, 0.4, 2.1, -3.1, 2.4, -0.8 ]
```

Need to make that become:

```
df['uv_acct']=[ 100.0, 101.5, 101.9, 104.0, 100.8, 103.2, 102.4 ]
```

So the formula would be:

```
uv_acct  = uv_acct[-1] * (1 + (pct_chg/100) )
```

one twist is that the index is set to a date.

this does work but I know it is not the most efficient approach.

```
for x in range ( len ( df ) ):

    # first month - starting index value
    if x == 0:
        df [ 'uv_acct' ] =  100 
    else:
        df [ 'uv_acct' ] = df [ 'uv_acct' ].iloc [ x - 1 ] * (1 + df [ 'pct_acct' ].iloc [ x ])
```

What is the best approach to create such an index base on the initial value of 100?

Thank you.  Cheers.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you rewrite the question. As written, it makes no sense, at least to me.

Comment: You add 100 to the current value?

Comment: start at 100 and then add to it going forward.

Comment: 101.5 * (1 + 0.4%) = 101.906. How do you get 105.5?

Comment: 100 to start, next month is 1.5% == 101.5

Comment: see a bad value on the next one, will change. sorry

Comment: @diogenes - can you add all values in expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`np.cumprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html)

```
import numpy as np

pct_chg = np.array([0, 1.5, 0.4, 2.1, -3.1, 2.4, -0.8])
uv_acct = 100 * np.cumprod(1 + pct_chg / 100)
```

Output:

```
# array([ 100.        ,  101.5       ,  101.906     ,  104.046026  ,
#         100.82059919,  103.24029357,  102.41437123])
```

Comment: Never see that one before.  I knew there had to be a far better way!  Awesome, thanks.